# FROM clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a function in SQL server - TRIM

For example `TRIM(',' FROM @str)`

Documentation says - TRIM removes the space character char(32) or other specified characters from the start and end of a string.

But how does this function implemented in terms of sql? Why does FROM allowed there?
Official docs says that
In Transact-SQL, the FROM clause is available on the following statements:
DELETE
UPDATE
SELECT.
But I don't see select, update or delete here. How does it works? How can I implement similar function? Where is documentation for this feature at all?

Comment: Can you give a link to the documentation you are looking at?

Comment: Wow - never even knew sql server supported that [weird syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). And MS did a crappy job of including samples that demonstrate the functionality

Comment: *"Where is documentation for this feature at all?"* Where *all* the documentation for Microsoft Products are, on http://learn.microsoft.com. If you go to the SQL Server documentation on that site, you can easily find the documentation for [TRIM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Alternatively, you can also use your favourite Search Engine and search "TRIM SQL Server", and I don't doubt that'll it'll be in the top 3 (if not top 1) results.

Comment: Weird syntax? It's ANSI SQL...

Comment: @SMor if you think the documentation isn't good enough, you can always make a pull request; all of SQL Server's documentation is open source. :)

Comment: Keywords may turn up in various unrelated places. `As` is used for column and table aliases and in the [`cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. So it goes.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I could make a suggestion, like the many others that I've made over the years.

Comment: @jarlh But ltrim and rtrim don't use that syntax. Just because it is ANSI standard does not make it "less weird" - like the old and error-prone but still very much standard of joining via the where clause.

Comment: @SMor, the optional `FROM` keyword is is part of the ISO SQL standard  `TRIM` function. LTRIM/RTRIM are proprietary T-SQL extensions so I guess MS chose not tot implement the noise keyword.

Comment: @Larnu I know the url to sql server documentation. I meant that I cannot find documentation to why FROM is allowed here

Comment: The Documentation *does* show you though. It even gives an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b--removes-specified-characters-from-both-sides-of-string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use of `FROM` has nothing to do with the `FROM` clause in a `SELECT` (or `UPDATE` or `DELETE`) statement.

It is simply the syntax for this particular function call.  I think this form of the function is specified by the SQL standard.

Another case of such ambiguity -- that I can readily think of -- is `GROUPING` which is used for both `GROUPING SETS` and as a special function.  There are probably others as well.